# C Macro - was not declared in this scope error

Tags: c, macros

```
#define SET_NONEMPTY(x) { const NString& var = r->hdrs->get_##x(); \
  if (!var.empty()) { \
    set_##x_for_serving(r->request, var.data(), var.length()); \
  } \
}
```

The above macro tries to set a request member if it is not empty, but I get this following 
error: 'set_x_for_serving' was not declared in this scope while I use this macro.

What is wrong in the above macro?

Comment: the OP's code highlighting would let me suggest that there is a syntax error which interrupts the multi line macro, because of the token concatenation.

Comment: It's a macro, that's what's wrong with it. If you must live with macros, change `set_##x_for_serving` to `set_ ## x ## _for_serving`.

Comment: How in the world is this offtopic?

Answer (score 9):

You need the [token-pasting operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation) on both sides of `x` in order to get it to substitute correctly.

```
#define SET_NONEMPTY(x) { const NString& var = r->hdrs->get_##x(); \
  if (!var.empty()) { \
    set_##x##_for_serving(r->request, var.data(), var.length()); \
  } \
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like inside a macro call of `SET_NONEMPTY(foobar)`, you expect that `set_##x_for_serving` will expand to `set_foobar_for_serving`.

**Is that correct?**

If so, the phrase `x_for_serving` is a *single token* and the `x` will not be seen by the preprocessor as an item to replace.

I think you want `set_##x##_for_serving` instead:

```
#define SET_NONEMPTY(x) { const NString& var = r->hdrs->get_##x(); \
  if (!var.empty()) {                                              \
    set_##x##_for_serving(r->request, var.data(), var.length());   \
  }                                                                \
}
```